# Passing long strings via POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, base64, encodeuricomponent

I have a requirement to post multiple long strings (base64 url) to a php where it will decode them and save as images on the server. I POST these base64 urls as an array using jQuery's `$.post()` to the php. But on some occasions I do not see all mages on the server. What might be causing for this?

I tried increasing the below in php.ini

```
post_max_size 100M
upload_max_filesize 100M
```

I use html2canvas to create png's via `toDataURL('image/png')`. Should I do `encodeURIComponent` before passing base64 to php?

Comment: just how long are these strings? obviously if theyr'e 100M+1byte, then your new limit is useless. and what kind of debugging have you done? did you check if your jquery is actually building the b64 strings properly, or even at all?

Comment: @MarcB thanks. jQuery builds the base64's correctly. I've test it using console. I'm short of ideas as to what should be done to rectify this issue.

Comment: then what about `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: How many base64 urls are in the array you are sending? Have you tried making multiple calls smaller arrays? Does the behaviour still occur?

Comment: @DelightedD0D thanks. There are 10 - 16 long base64 urls.

Comment: @MarcB I haven't tried that. I'll do that now.

Comment: What exactly is happening? Are you getting broken images, or are some of the images not making it to the database at all? If it is the latter, are you getting some of the images from a single POSTed array but not others, or is it that sometimes you POST the array and NONE of that array's images are stored? Try to be more specific.